# Checkbox! When Selecting one item Another item also get selected in RecyclerView?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a recycler view with some text and a checked box I want that when user select the checkbox only current item is select but when I scroll down the list
another item also got selected I don't know what is the problem with my code.
I checked out all the solution provided by StackOverflow but no one is work for me.
Kindly tell me what is the problem with my code?

My adapter Class is:

```
public class MyAdapter extends
        RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

    Context context;
    List<GetAdvReqPackagesListResponse.PackageList> packageList;
    private View rootView;

    public MyAdapter (List<GetAdvReqPackagesListResponse.PackageList> packageList,
                                              Context context) {
        this.context = context;
        this.packageList = packageList;
    }

    public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        TextView textPackageCode, textPackageDesc, textLaborTU, textLaborAmt,
                textPartsCount, textPartsAmt, textPackageTotal;

        CheckBox chkBoxSelectPackage;

        public MyViewHolder(View rowView) {
            super(rowView);

            rootView = rowView;

            textPackageCode = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.textPackageCode);
            textPackageDesc = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.textPackageDesc);
            textLaborTU = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.textLaborTU);
            textLaborAmt = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.textLaborAmt);
            textPartsCount = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.textPartsCount);
            textPartsAmt = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.textPartsAmt);
            textPackageTotal = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.textPackageTotal);
            chkBoxSelectPackage = (CheckBox) rowView.findViewById(R.id.chkBoxSelectPackage);

        }
    }

    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.shopping_cart_row_item_adv_req_package_list, parent, false);

        return new MyViewHolder(itemView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final MyViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        final GetAdvReqPackagesListResponse.PackageList packageList1 = packageList.get(position);


        holder.textPackageCode.setText(packageList.get(position).code);
        holder.textPackageDesc.setText(packageList.get(position).description);

        if (packageList.get(position).laborTU.equalsIgnoreCase("0"))
            holder.textLaborTU.setText(String.valueOf("-"));
        else
            holder.textLaborTU.setText(packageList.get(position).laborTU);

        if (packageList.get(position).laborAmt.equalsIgnoreCase("0"))
            holder.textLaborAmt.setText(String.valueOf("-"));
        else
            holder.textLaborAmt.setText(CurrencySymbol.currencySymbol(Constant.appCurrencyCode) + " "
                    + packageList.get(position).laborAmt);

        if (packageList.get(position).partCount.equalsIgnoreCase("0"))
            holder.textPartsCount.setText(String.valueOf("-"));
        else
            holder.textPartsCount.setText(packageList.get(position).partCount);

        if (packageList.get(position).partAmt.equalsIgnoreCase("0"))
            holder.textPartsAmt.setText(String.valueOf("-"));
        else
            holder.textPartsAmt.setText(CurrencySymbol.currencySymbol(Constant.appCurrencyCode) + " "
                    + packageList.get(position).partAmt);


        holder.chkBoxSelectPackage.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {


            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {


                if (isChecked == true) {
                    holder.chkBoxSelectPackage.setChecked(true);

                    holder.textPackageCode.setTextAppearance(context, R.style.font_color_green_size_13sp);
                    holder.textPackageDesc.setTextAppearance(context, R.style.font_color_green_size_13sp);
                    holder.textLaborTU.setTextAppearance(context, R.style.font_color_green_size_13sp);
                    holder.textLaborAmt.setTextAppearance(context, R.style.font_color_green_size_13sp);
                    holder.textPartsCount.setTextAppearance(context, R.style.font_color_green_size_13sp);
                    holder.textPartsAmt.setTextAppearance(context, R.style.font_color_green_size_13sp);
                } else if (isChecked == false) {
                    holder.chkBoxSelectPackage.setChecked(false);

                    holder.textPackageCode.setTextAppearance(context, R.style.font_small_color_black_size_13sp);
                    holder.textPackageDesc.setTextAppearance(context, R.style.font_small_color_black_size_13sp);
                    holder.textLaborTU.setTextAppearance(context, R.style.font_small_color_black_size_13sp);
                    holder.textLaborAmt.setTextAppearance(context, R.style.font_small_color_black_size_13sp);
                    holder.textPartsCount.setTextAppearance(context, R.style.font_small_color_black_size_13sp);
                    holder.textPartsAmt.setTextAppearance(context, R.style.font_small_color_black_size_13sp);


                }


            }
        });


    }


    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return packageList.size();
    }

}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It is quite easy, you should clear or overwrite check state on every `onBindViewHolder`. Holders are reused, so you can get already "binded" before item

Comment: How to do that? @Eugen Martynon

Comment: Five answers for such simple question :) You should keep track of checkboxes state by adding to your model or having array with states

Answer (score 1):

Add one paramter Selection_flag in your GetAdvReqPackagesListResponse.PackageList  and initialize to zero

```
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final MyViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        final GetAdvReqPackagesListResponse.PackageList packageList1 = packageList.get(position);

        if (packageList.get(position).getSelection_flag().equals("1")) {
            subHolder.chkBoxSelectPackage.setChecked(true);
        } else {
            subHolder.chkBoxSelectPackage.setChecked(false);

        }


        holder.chkBoxSelectPackage.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {


        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {


            if (isChecked == true) {
               //holder.chkBoxSelectPackage.setChecked(true);
               packageList.get(position).setSelection_flag("1");

                holder.textPackageCode.setTextAppearance(context, R.style.font_color_green_size_13sp);
                holder.textPackageDesc.setTextAppearance(context, R.style.font_color_green_size_13sp);
                holder.textLaborTU.setTextAppearance(context, R.style.font_color_green_size_13sp);
                holder.textLaborAmt.setTextAppearance(context, R.style.font_color_green_size_13sp);
                holder.textPartsCount.setTextAppearance(context, R.style.font_color_green_size_13sp);
                holder.textPartsAmt.setTextAppearance(context, R.style.font_color_green_size_13sp);
            } else if (isChecked == false) {
               // holder.chkBoxSelectPackage.setChecked(false);
                packageList.get(position).setSelection_flag("0");
                holder.textPackageCode.setTextAppearance(context, R.style.font_small_color_black_size_13sp);
                holder.textPackageDesc.setTextAppearance(context, R.style.font_small_color_black_size_13sp);
                holder.textLaborTU.setTextAppearance(context, R.style.font_small_color_black_size_13sp);
                holder.textLaborAmt.setTextAppearance(context, R.style.font_small_color_black_size_13sp);
                holder.textPartsCount.setTextAppearance(context, R.style.font_small_color_black_size_13sp);
                holder.textPartsAmt.setTextAppearance(context, R.style.font_small_color_black_size_13sp);


            }

            notifyDataSetChanged();             
    }
```

Comment: have you  added Selection_flag  in your model class?

Comment: post your GetAdvReqPackagesListResponse.PackageList class

Comment: My Model class is Parcelable class all data come from API

Comment: Yes  post that  Model class.And add Selection_flag parameter and getter setter for Selection_flag

Answer (score 0):

Add a variable "isSelected" to your model calss of PackageList and create getter setter for it.

Then update onBindViewHolder function in your adapter class like below:

```
public class MyAdapter extends
        RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

    Context context;
    List<GetAdvReqPackagesListResponse.PackageList> packageList;
    private View rootView;

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final MyViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        final GetAdvReqPackagesListResponse.PackageList packageList1 = packageList.get(position);


        holder.textPackageCode.setText(packageList.get(position).code);
        holder.textPackageDesc.setText(packageList.get(position).description);

        if (packageList.get(position).laborTU.equalsIgnoreCase("0"))
            holder.textLaborTU.setText(String.valueOf("-"));
        else
            holder.textLaborTU.setText(packageList.get(position).laborTU);

        if (packageList.get(position).laborAmt.equalsIgnoreCase("0"))
            holder.textLaborAmt.setText(String.valueOf("-"));
        else
            holder.textLaborAmt.setText(CurrencySymbol.currencySymbol(Constant.appCurrencyCode) + " "
                    + packageList.get(position).laborAmt);

        if (packageList.get(position).partCount.equalsIgnoreCase("0"))
            holder.textPartsCount.setText(String.valueOf("-"));
        else
            holder.textPartsCount.setText(packageList.get(position).partCount);

        if (packageList.get(position).partAmt.equalsIgnoreCase("0"))
            holder.textPartsAmt.setText(String.valueOf("-"));
        else
            holder.textPartsAmt.setText(CurrencySymbol.currencySymbol(Constant.appCurrencyCode) + " "
                    + packageList.get(position).partAmt);


        holder.chkBoxSelectPackage.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                packageList.get(position).setSelected(isChecked)
            }
        });

        setItemSelected(holder, packageList.get(position).isSelected);

    }

    private void setItemSelected(final MyViewHolder holder, boolean isSelected){
        if(isSelected){
            holder.chkBoxSelectPackage.setChecked(true);
            holder.textPackageCode.setTextAppearance(context, R.style.font_color_green_size_13sp);
            holder.textPackageDesc.setTextAppearance(context, R.style.font_color_green_size_13sp);
            holder.textLaborTU.setTextAppearance(context, R.style.font_color_green_size_13sp);
            holder.textLaborAmt.setTextAppearance(context, R.style.font_color_green_size_13sp);
            holder.textPartsCount.setTextAppearance(context, R.style.font_color_green_size_13sp);
            holder.textPartsAmt.setTextAppearance(context, R.style.font_color_green_size_13sp);
        } else{
            holder.chkBoxSelectPackage.setChecked(false);
            holder.textPackageCode.setTextAppearance(context, R.style.font_small_color_black_size_13sp);
            holder.textPackageDesc.setTextAppearance(context, R.style.font_small_color_black_size_13sp);
            holder.textLaborTU.setTextAppearance(context, R.style.font_small_color_black_size_13sp);
            holder.textLaborAmt.setTextAppearance(context, R.style.font_small_color_black_size_13sp);
            holder.textPartsCount.setTextAppearance(context, R.style.font_small_color_black_size_13sp);
            holder.textPartsAmt.setTextAppearance(context, R.style.font_small_color_black_size_13sp);
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You said that you want to select only current Item. If you want to select only one item then use **RadioButton** instead of **Checkbox**.

Keep a reference of you selected RadioButton like

```
private RadioButton lastChecked_CB = null;
private static int selectedPosition = -1;
```

Then in **onBindViewHolder()**

```
if (position == selectedPosition) {
    holder.myRadioButton.setChecked(true);
    lastChecked_CB = holder.myRadioButton;
}

holder.myRadioButton.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, final boolean isChecked) {

        if (lastChecked_CB != null) {
            lastChecked_CB.setChecked(false);
        }

        holder.myRadioButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                lastChecked_CB = holder.myRadioButton;
                selectedPosition = holder.getAdapterPosition();
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This will happen because position gets rearranged while scrolling. Below code will help you to solve the issue, I have posted the `onBindViewHolder` method code alone

```
private SparseArray<SparseBooleanArray> sparseArray = new SparseArray<>();

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, final int position) {


                holder.selectEnrollment.setId(position);
                holder.selectEnrollment.setChecked(false);

            if (sparseArray.get(holder.selectEnrollment.getId()) != null) {
                boolean isChecked = sparseArray.get(holder.selectEnrollment.getId()).get(holder.selectEnrollment.getId());
                holder.selectEnrollment.setChecked(isChecked);
            }

    holder.selectEnrollment.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    sparseArray.clear();

            SparseBooleanArray checkedPosition = new SparseBooleanArray();
            checkedPosition.put(v.getId(), true);
            sparseArray.put(tagId, checkedPosition);
            notifySetDataChanged();
                }
            });


    }
```

Hope this is helpful :)

Comment: You just pasted up another answer . I told already that I checked out all the answer can you please tell me where to change in my code?

Comment: @Champandorid: In your code you had to handle the set the selected `checkbox` making true in 'onBinViewHolder'.i.e., is what  I did in this code. Kindly have a look at this code. For this issue you will get code like this only